# how to choose an array element by using click function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

this is an array. i want to click on any element of the array and then want to display the clicked element. if i click on "with" then with will be displayed on the screen.

var answer_1 = ["down", "by", "over", "with", "throught"];

how to do it using JavaScript?

Comment: Your question does not include all the details we need to know in order to answer. When you say _"click on any element of the array"_, how is that array displayed on the screen? And when you say _"displayed on the script"_, what do you mean? Where? Please include the code you've tried to write for this, and maybe we'll be able to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will be useful for you

```
$.each(answer_1, function(index, val){
  console.log(index + ' - '+ val);
});
```

this way you can acces the index and then call a function with the index, its a lot easier if you use a template system, but its the same idea

Comment: but how can i trace which index is clicked?

Comment: with a function passing the index, for example inside the each you can create elements and add a function
<p onclick="myFunction(index)"></p>

then in myFunction(index) you just have to acces your array
answer_1[index]

Comment: $('h3').click(function() {
    $('#out').append('<p>' + $('answer_1').index(this) + '</p>');
});    I tried this. It always displays -1 as the index number.

Comment: show me the function in wich you print the h3 elements

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/613m5t45/   please click on the blue text.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/f7rcq1hp/1/